# Turning an argument into a receiver

Tags: ruby

I created the following extension

```
class String
  def is_a_number? s  # check if string is either an INT or a FLOAT (12, 12.2, 12.23 would return true)
    s.to_s.match(/\A[+-]?\d+?(\.\d+)?\Z/) == nil ? false : true
  end
end
```

How can I make it work as a chained method?

```
is_a_number?("10") # returns true
"10".is_a_number? # returns an error (missing arguments)
```

**Update**

Thanks sawa, mikej and Ramon for their answers. As suggested, I changed the class to Object and got rid of the argument (s):

```
class Object
  def is_a_number?  # check if string is either an INT or a FLOAT (12, 12.2, 12.23 would return true)
    to_s.match(/\A[+-]?\d+?(\.\d+)?\Z/) != nil
  end
end
```

It now works perfectly fine:

```
23.23.is_a_number? # > true
```

Thanks guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `"10".is_a_number?`, you already have the object `"10"` you want to check for, which is the receiver of `is_a_number?`, so your method doesn't need to take any parameters.

Because `match` is an instance method on `String`, you don't need to specify a receiver for it. It will just operate on the same object on which `is_a_number?` was called. Because you know you already have a `String` object, the `to_s` isn't needed either.

Just write it as:

```
class String
  # check if string is either an INT or a FLOAT (12, 12.2, 12.23 would return true)
  def is_a_number? 
    match(/\A[+-]?\d+?(\.\d+)?\Z/) != nil
  end
end
```

[Ramon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199288/ramon) suggestion that you may want to put your extension on `Object` rather than on `String` is a good point if you don't know if the object you're testing is going to be a string.

---

Also, what you're describing isn't really what is meant by *method chaining*; it's just calling a method on an object. Method chaining is where the return types of methods are set up so that several methods can be called in sequence e.g in Rails, something like

```
User.where(:name => 'Mike').limit(3) # find the first 3 Mikes
```

is an example of method chaining.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to patch `Object` instead of `String` (since you are calling `to_s`):

```
class Object
  def is_a_number?
    to_s.match(/\A[+-]?\d+?(\.\d+)?\Z/).nil?
  end
end
```

You could also look at replacing with it with `validates numericality: true` on your model.